# Display products with following HTML code using Datalist

Tags: html, asp.net, css

Please give me suggestion that how can I show following HTML in `<asp:DataList /`> or `<asp:GridView />` without affecting other contents in page.

```
<div class="products">
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
    <ul>\\Products
        <li> <a href="#"><img src="css/images/Newly_Launched/HTC_One_801e_GSM_Mobile_Phone.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
            <div class="product-info">
                 <h3>Newly Arraival</h3>

                <div class="product-desc">
                    <p>HTC One 801e GSM Mobile phone</p> <strong class="price">Rs. 42,990</strong>

                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#"><img src="css/images/Newly_Launched/MIcrosoft_Xbox_360_Slim_4GB.jpg" alt="" /></a>

            <div class="product-info">
                 <h3>Newly Arraival</h3>

                <div class="product-desc">
                     <h4>&nbsp;</h4>

                    <p>Microsoft xbox 360 slim 4gb&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p> <strong class="price">Rs. 26,990</strong> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please let us know what have tried till now?

Answer (score 0):

Please use Repeater Instead

```
<div class="products">
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
    <ul>\\Products
       <asp:Repeater id="rp" runat="server">
```

" alt="" /> 
                
                     <%#Eval("Title") %>/h3>

```
                <div class="product-desc">
                    <p><%#Eval("Description") %></p> <strong class="price">Rs. <%#Eval("Price") %></strong>

                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Repeater for it

```
<div class="products">
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
    <ul>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <li>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src='<%#Eval("Image") %>' alt="" /></a>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <h3><%#Eval("Title") %></h3>

                    <div class="product-desc">
                        <p><%#Eval("Name") %></p>
                        <strong class="price"><%#Eval("Price") %></strong>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </li>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ul>
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `<asp:GridView />`, then you need to design ItemTemplate somewhat like below. This is for your reference, set datasource and change `Eval("____")` property name accordingly.

```
<div class="products">
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
    <asp:GridView ID="grdProducts" runat="server" Width="100%" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="#"><img src='<%# Eval("ImageURL") %>' alt="" /></a> 
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h3>New Arrival</h3>
                        <div class="product-desc">
                            <p><%# Eval("Description") %></p> <strong class="price"><%# Eval("Price") %></strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>              
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```